# Drupal custom module is not working

Tags: php, drupal-7, drupal-modules

Here is my custom.info

```
name = Custom
description = Custom module
core = 7.x
package = Own
```

and custom.module

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 * An example custom module for selecting, updating and deleting query
 */

/**
 * Implementation of hook_block_info()
 */
echo 'Today: \n';
echo date('m/d/Y');

function custom_block_info() {
    $block['custom'] = array('info' => t('Custom block'))   
    return $block;
} 

/**
 * Implements hook_block_view.
 */
function custom_block_view($delta = '') {
  global $user;
  $block['content'] = t('Hello @user from IP @host',array(
    '@user' => format_username($user), 
    '@host' => $user->hostname`enter code here`
  ));

  $result = db_select('node','a')
    ->fields('a', array('title'))
    ->execute();

  foreach($result as $node) { 
    $items[] = array(
      'data' => t($node->title)
    );
  }

  $block['content'] .= theme('item_list', array(
    'items' => $items
  ));

  return $block;
}
```

But this custom module is not displaying data in the sidebar where had i put the block. i have place the echo statement above the code it's not even displaying that echo statement in block can any one tell me how to resolve this????

P.S. I have installed drupal i ve changed nothing in database!

Answer (score 1):

Check if your module is active in the modules list *(admin/modules)* if so try to put your echo statements in a hook_init like this:

```
function custom_init(){
    echo 'Today: \n';
    echo date('m/d/Y');
}
```

then clear all drupal cache **Configuration > Performance > Clear alla caches** *(admin/config/development/performance)*

Comment: Yes you are right, i didn't enable the module in modules section.

Comment: But now something big come up:
HTTP error 0 occurred when trying to fetch http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/context-7.x-3.0-beta6.tar.gz.
Unable to retrieve Drupal project from http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/context-7.x-3.0-beta6.tar.gz.
Now this error comes up when installing module? what can be the issue permissions???

Comment: I have no idea why it happens...sorry...maybe is the configuration of your server.